# Is there a good aggregate equivalent for Google Sheets with the large function?

Tags: random, google-sheets, aggregate, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I try to write an easy randomizer based on a database for randomly combining data. This works fine in Excel, but not in Google Sheets, because there is no `aggregat`

I've already tried `LARGE` and `MAX` but then it's not randomizing, and with SUBTOTAL it's not working. I thought it also could be based on `ROW`, but maybe I have a wrong concept.

The code in excel is like this (i use the German version of Excel, but this should be the English equivalent)

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ";TRUE;INDIRECT("A"&ROUNDUP(RAND()*AGGREGAT(14;4;(A:A<>"")*ROW(A:A);1);0));INDIRECT("B"&ROUNDUP(RAND()*AGGREGAT(14;4;(B:B<>"")*ROW(B:B);1);0));INDIRECT("C"&ROUNDUP(RAND()*AGGREGAT(14;4;(C:C<>"")*ROW(C:C);1);0)))
```

As I mentioned there is no `aggregat`, and the other solutions I looked up didn't work for me.

Comment: Here is a document where you can look it up
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1USg9VCNgjYgz_THlJaC7tWcFnjgIuVyPyAHqw5gL8cI/edit?usp=sharing

The expected output should be a randomised sentence (here in german)

Comment: do you want a random cell to be picked up from any of those columns? (A, B, C) is that what you are after?

Comment: Yes, In a way that random sentences wollne created

Comment: so you want to pick 3 random cells from 3 columns and create a sentence?

Comment: I want to pic one random cell in each column, To get one full sentence made of one random word of each column.

Comment: perhaps try the last formula from the answer

Comment: That did it perfectly. Thanks! It is also way more effecient than my previous atempt. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Google Sheets, there are multiple formulae that can mimic `AGGREGATE` such as `QUERY`, `FILTER`, `VLOOKUP`, `HLOOKUP`, `LOOKUP`, `INDEX`/`MATCH` and depends on a task which of these mentioned suits best.

---

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)); RANDBETWEEN(1; COUNTA(A1:A)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=INDEX({INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A))\
        INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B1:B))\
        INDIRECT("C1:C"&COUNTA(C1:C))}; RANDBETWEEN(1; COUNTA(A1:A)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
={INDEX(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)); RANDBETWEEN(1; COUNTA(A1:A)))\
  INDEX(INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B1:B)); RANDBETWEEN(1; COUNTA(B1:B)))\
  INDEX(INDIRECT("C1:C"&COUNTA(C1:C)); RANDBETWEEN(1; COUNTA(C1:C)))}
```

[image: 3]

---

```
=INDEX({INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A));
            INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B1:B));
            INDIRECT("C1:C"&COUNTA(C1:C))}; RANDBETWEEN(1; COUNTA(A1:C)))
```

[image: 4]

---

```
=JOIN(" "; {PROPER(
 INDEX(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)); RANDBETWEEN(1; COUNTA(A1:A))))\
 INDEX(INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B1:B)); RANDBETWEEN(1; COUNTA(B1:B)))\
 INDEX(INDIRECT("C1:C"&COUNTA(C1:C)); RANDBETWEEN(1; COUNTA(C1:C)))})&"."
```

[image: 0]